# How to make java program read from CCID Card on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, security, macos, usb, certificate

I have a java code that run in Windows and does this:

```
String config = "name = SafeSign \n"+
        "library = c:\\windows\\system32\\aetpkss1.dll";
Security.addProvider(new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes())));
```

I want to transform this code so it will run on Mac OS X. Basically, this code is part of something that will read a certificate from a CCID Card that is connected to my mac via usb.

I've read that mac uses pcsclite lib in this driver, but I don't know how to locate which file I must reference on the config variable. Here is also the information about the Card reader I'm using:

```
CCID USB Reader:

  Product ID:   0x90cc
  Vendor ID:    0x072f
  Version:   1.00
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: ACS
  Location ID:  0x06200000
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
```

Any different ideas or pointers about how I would be able to do what I want would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Mac user, but this [blog post](http://www.redelijkheid.com/blog/2008/12/10/safesign-and-osx.html) seems to point to `/usr/local/lib/libaetpkss.dylib`?

You may also want to look at the [OpenSC](http://www.opensc-project.org/sca/wiki/OpenscTokend) project which possibly supports you AET card.

Comment: I tried this dynamic library, but it doesn't work. Apparently, java for some reason can't recognize this library. It looks like a 32-bit 64-bit compatibility problem between the library and java (as far as I know).

Comment: Mac OS X typically wants native libraries to by named libfoo.jnilib.